# Position y and x label at the middle of 2x2 subplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I got a figure with subplots from Matlab using `matlab2tikz` function but I don't like the fact that all figures have their own y and labels. I'd like to position a label at the middle of the big figure as shown in the image below? I hope my MWE works for you.

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: on}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    ylabel absolute,
    label style={font=\footnotesize,align=center},
    yticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=5},
    xticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=5},
    legend style = {font=\scriptsize},
    title style = {font=\scriptsize,yshift=-2ex},
  },
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.5pt,line cap=round},
}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}
  %% the following commands are needed for some matlab2tikz features
  \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
  \usepackage{grffile}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=5cm,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4cm,font=\bfseries},
    child/.style={draw,align=center,text width=3cm},
    grandchild/.style={align=left,text width=2cm}
}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figurewidth{.725\linewidth}
\setlength\figureheight{.4\linewidth}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%

\begin{document}





\begin{figure}
  \centering

  % This file was created by matlab2tikz.
  %
  %The latest updates can be retrieved from
  %  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
  %where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
  %
  \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(0.758in,2.554in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=40,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    6.02502531495016\\
  20    6.03786871814991\\
  30    6.05918985377419\\
  40    6.08886699413247\\
  60    6.17254544862453\\
  70    6.22570081489845\\
  80    6.28662779885325\\
  90.0000000000001  6.35463211182034\\
  100   6.4294125699592\\
  200   7.46591308115097\\
  300   8.78144761951078\\
  400   10.136509145617\\
  500   11.4222338684283\\
  600   12.6036026770424\\
  700   13.6825207466473\\
  800   14.66195948202\\
  900.000000000001  15.5620897919143\\
  1000  16.3867155871367\\
  3000  25.5515280292327\\
  4000  28.0389740607155\\
  5000  29.9823612547385\\
  6000  31.5379616627357\\
  7000  32.8534855740365\\
  8000  34.0671811172936\\
  9000.00000000001  35.0845580745873\\
  10000 36.0116071516141\\
  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(3.327in,2.554in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=-12,
  ymax=-8,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    -10.0570025948884\\
  20    -10.0570031434668\\
  30    -10.0570032516035\\
  40    -10.0570074959765\\
  60    -10.0569978089629\\
  70    -10.05699132459\\
  80    -10.0570356801329\\
  90.0000000000001  -10.0570378448397\\
  100   -10.0570620777555\\
  200   -10.0572086017414\\
  300   -10.0569966527061\\
  400   -10.054844222969\\
  500   -10.0556254978021\\
  600   -10.0563097062558\\
  700   -10.056059216611\\
  800   -10.0581061739041\\
  900.000000000001  -10.0523735647241\\
  1000  -10.052976948968\\
  3000  -10.0593091075301\\
  4000  -10.0365266583425\\
  5000  -10.0137299415955\\
  6000  -10.0622173106068\\
  7000  -10.0980844470786\\
  8000  -9.98687857886295\\
  9000.00000000001  -9.99348051550582\\
  10000 -9.96814078801037\\
  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=-12,
  ymax=-8,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    -10.0570025945993\\
  20    -10.0570030506854\\
  30    -10.0570031144715\\
  40    -10.0570074041838\\
  60    -10.0569975290144\\
  70    -10.0569886415872\\
  80    -10.0570323392666\\
  90.0000000000001  -10.0570340650878\\
  100   -10.0570584321855\\
  200   -10.0572005583724\\
  300   -10.0570005486271\\
  400   -10.0548409756516\\
  500   -10.0554633512654\\
  600   -10.0563301863098\\
  700   -10.0562893716279\\
  800   -10.0579856199545\\
  900.000000000001  -10.0520240983566\\
  1000  -10.0568915872956\\
  3000  -10.051564746664\\
  4000  -10.0268907864406\\
  5000  -10.0126815753164\\
  6000  -10.0679558888649\\
  7000  -10.0979902405306\\
  8000  -9.98497209704108\\
  9000.00000000001  -9.98102335041346\\
  10000 -9.96657990322325\\
  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(3.327in,0.481in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=40,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    6.02502532663188\\
  20    6.03786874364145\\
  30    6.05918988451697\\
  40    6.08886704374304\\
  60    6.17254551850378\\
  70    6.22570167429446\\
  80    6.2866287687612\\
  90.0000000000001  6.35463320389361\\
  100   6.42941379238741\\
  200   7.4659154555193\\
  300   8.78145134644068\\
  400   10.136511685466\\
  500   11.4222167144186\\
  600   12.6036297490859\\
  700   13.6824975364228\\
  800   14.6619614864612\\
  900.000000000001  15.5621034875103\\
  1000  16.3828067673392\\
  3000  25.5591255050665\\
  4000  28.0497587880991\\
  5000  29.9824517969779\\
  6000  31.530570397572\\
  7000  32.8535234900969\\
  8000  34.0672090589387\\
  9000.00000000001  35.0845680270891\\
  10000 36.0116458449977\\
  };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `name=ax1`, `name=ax2` etc. to the options of the four `axis` environments, you can place nodes relative to the corners of the axes, using for example

```
\path (ax1.south west) -- (ax3.north west)
  node[midway,left=7mm,anchor=south,rotate=90] {Magnitude};
\path (ax3.south east) -- (ax4.south west)
  node[midway,below=7mm] {Frequency};
```

Place this inside the `tikzpicture`, after the last `axis`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    ylabel absolute,
    label style={font=\footnotesize,align=center},
    yticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=5},
    xticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=5},
    legend style = {font=\scriptsize},
    title style = {font=\scriptsize,yshift=-2ex},
  },
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.5pt,line cap=round},
}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}
  %% the following commands are needed for some matlab2tikz features
  \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
  \usepackage{grffile}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=5cm,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4cm,font=\bfseries},
    child/.style={draw,align=center,text width=3cm},
    grandchild/.style={align=left,text width=2cm}
}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figurewidth{.725\linewidth}
\setlength\figureheight{.4\linewidth}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%

\begin{document}





\begin{figure}
  \centering

  % This file was created by matlab2tikz.
  %
  %The latest updates can be retrieved from
  %  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
  %where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
  %
  \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[%
  name=ax1,
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(0.758in,2.554in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=40,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    6.02502531495016\\
  20    6.03786871814991\\
  30    6.05918985377419\\
  40    6.08886699413247\\
  60    6.17254544862453\\
  70    6.22570081489845\\
  80    6.28662779885325\\
  90.0000000000001  6.35463211182034\\
  100   6.4294125699592\\
  200   7.46591308115097\\
  300   8.78144761951078\\
  400   10.136509145617\\
  500   11.4222338684283\\
  600   12.6036026770424\\
  700   13.6825207466473\\
  800   14.66195948202\\
  900.000000000001  15.5620897919143\\
  1000  16.3867155871367\\
  3000  25.5515280292327\\
  4000  28.0389740607155\\
  5000  29.9823612547385\\
  6000  31.5379616627357\\
  7000  32.8534855740365\\
  8000  34.0671811172936\\
  9000.00000000001  35.0845580745873\\
  10000 36.0116071516141\\
  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  name=ax2,
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(3.327in,2.554in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=-12,
  ymax=-8,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    -10.0570025948884\\
  20    -10.0570031434668\\
  30    -10.0570032516035\\
  40    -10.0570074959765\\
  60    -10.0569978089629\\
  70    -10.05699132459\\
  80    -10.0570356801329\\
  90.0000000000001  -10.0570378448397\\
  100   -10.0570620777555\\
  200   -10.0572086017414\\
  300   -10.0569966527061\\
  400   -10.054844222969\\
  500   -10.0556254978021\\
  600   -10.0563097062558\\
  700   -10.056059216611\\
  800   -10.0581061739041\\
  900.000000000001  -10.0523735647241\\
  1000  -10.052976948968\\
  3000  -10.0593091075301\\
  4000  -10.0365266583425\\
  5000  -10.0137299415955\\
  6000  -10.0622173106068\\
  7000  -10.0980844470786\\
  8000  -9.98687857886295\\
  9000.00000000001  -9.99348051550582\\
  10000 -9.96814078801037\\
  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  name=ax3,
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=-12,
  ymax=-8,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    -10.0570025945993\\
  20    -10.0570030506854\\
  30    -10.0570031144715\\
  40    -10.0570074041838\\
  60    -10.0569975290144\\
  70    -10.0569886415872\\
  80    -10.0570323392666\\
  90.0000000000001  -10.0570340650878\\
  100   -10.0570584321855\\
  200   -10.0572005583724\\
  300   -10.0570005486271\\
  400   -10.0548409756516\\
  500   -10.0554633512654\\
  600   -10.0563301863098\\
  700   -10.0562893716279\\
  800   -10.0579856199545\\
  900.000000000001  -10.0520240983566\\
  1000  -10.0568915872956\\
  3000  -10.051564746664\\
  4000  -10.0268907864406\\
  5000  -10.0126815753164\\
  6000  -10.0679558888649\\
  7000  -10.0979902405306\\
  8000  -9.98497209704108\\
  9000.00000000001  -9.98102335041346\\
  10000 -9.96657990322325\\
  };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  name=ax4,
  width=1.952in,
  height=1.493in,
  at={(3.327in,0.481in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10000,
  xminorticks=true,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=40,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \addplot [color=mycolor1, dashdotted, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  10    6.02502532663188\\
  20    6.03786874364145\\
  30    6.05918988451697\\
  40    6.08886704374304\\
  60    6.17254551850378\\
  70    6.22570167429446\\
  80    6.2866287687612\\
  90.0000000000001  6.35463320389361\\
  100   6.42941379238741\\
  200   7.4659154555193\\
  300   8.78145134644068\\
  400   10.136511685466\\
  500   11.4222167144186\\
  600   12.6036297490859\\
  700   13.6824975364228\\
  800   14.6619614864612\\
  900.000000000001  15.5621034875103\\
  1000  16.3828067673392\\
  3000  25.5591255050665\\
  4000  28.0497587880991\\
  5000  29.9824517969779\\
  6000  31.530570397572\\
  7000  32.8535234900969\\
  8000  34.0672090589387\\
  9000.00000000001  35.0845680270891\\
  10000 36.0116458449977\\
  };
  \end{axis}

\path (ax1.south west) -- (ax3.north west)
  node[midway,left=7mm,anchor=south,rotate=90] {Magnitude};
\path (ax3.south east) -- (ax4.south west)
  node[midway,below=7mm] {Frequency};

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```