# How to label x and y-axes in pgfplotssets?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make four scatterplots in one figure with attaching only one label to x and y-axes. As far as I understood, axes need to be described after `\begin{axis}` command, but if I do so, only one scatterplot is being labeled. The code I used is below, any help is appreciated.

[image: Four scatter plots in one figure]

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}  
\begin{document}  
\pgfplotsset{small}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tabular}{rl}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks, black]  
table[meta=label] {  
x y label  
0.1 -0.5 a  
0.2 -0.6 a  
0.3 -0.7 a};  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}  
    &  
    \begin{tikzpicture}   
    \begin{axis}  
\addplot+[only marks, black]  
table[meta=label] {  
x y label
0.1 -0.5 a  
0.2 -0.6 a  
0.3 -0.7 a};  
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}  
    \\
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]  
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1, title=b,  
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,-0.2)},anchor=north},  
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.2,1)},anchor=south},  
    xlabel={X Label Here},  
    ylabel={Y Label Here}]  
\addplot+[only marks,  
black]  
table[meta=label] {  
x y label  
0.1 -0.5 a  
0.2 -0.6 a  
0.3 -0.7 a};  
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}%  
    &  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]  
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,  
    title=a]  
\addplot+[only marks,  
black]  
table[meta=label] {  
x y label  
0.1 -0.5 a  
0.2 -0.6 a  
0.3 -0.7 a};  
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}%  
    \\  
\end{tabular}%  
\end{center}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403911/position-y-and-x-label-at-the-middle-of-2x2-subplot/403913#403913